# Filling a complex object

Tags: extrude

I am currently working on filling a complex building structure to make it easier to 3d print on my small printer. when the object is scaled down the wall become paper thin and my print fails. I want to solidify the object by overlaying two objects and subtracting the excess (like a mold), and then merging them. I have tried extrusion, but as you can see there are many faces and it distorts the exterior. I want to preserve the exterior and fill the entire interior. I removed the bottom to start the process, but don't know where to go from here.  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you're considering seems overly complex for your intended outcome -- the inner faces should be much simpler than the outer complex structure, for example:

[image]

Also your "removed bottom" is showing leftover edges crossing the space, these can cause trouble during rendering or 3D printing.

Comment: wow that's exactly what I wanted to do! How do you do that without distorting the outside?

Comment: Glad you like it - remember, I don't have your model, just a screenshot of it.  I loaded that into Blender and made an optical illusion of an underside for it.  What you should do to get this on your model is to select every edge on the base and Extrude, then hit the escape key, then (without loosing the selection) Scale inward until you get the thickness you think you'll need.  If you need modeling help from there that goes beyond the scope of a 600-character comment, but if I've answered your question I'd appreciate it if you'd click the checkmark next to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your answer. Sorry I didn't know how to accept the answer.